# Scala, Spark-shell, Groupby failing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, spark-shell

I have Spark version 2.4.0 and scala version 2.11.12.  I can sucessfully load a dataframe with the following code.

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").option("mode","DROPMALFORMED").option("maxColumns",60000).load("MAR18.csv")
```

However, when I attempt to do a groupby the following I get an error.

```
df.groupby("S0102_gender").agg(sum("Respondent.Serial")).show()
```

The error message is:

> error: value groupby is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

What am I missing.  A complete Scala and Spark Newb.

Comment: It should be `groupBy` with capital B.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.  But I don't see where I can accept this as the correct answer.  Where is the check mark located.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Happy to help. Since the error is due to a simple typo you can simply delete the question :)

Comment: I appreciate the assist.

Comment: Sorry I am a python programmer trying to grok a superior language.  The kind response about the importance notation, went far in my understanding of dumb things I need to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of groupby it should be groupBy like below... clearly typo error.

```
df.groupBy("S0102_gender").agg(sum("Respondent.Serial")).show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo

Change

```
    groupby
```

To

```
    groupBy
```